# How to send SMS from Mobile in App built with Embarcedaro HTML5 Builder

Tags: html, sms, phonegap-build, builder, phonegap-desktop-app

I am trying to build an App in which I need to send SMS from Mobile.

I searched in the online help of HTML5 Builder but there is nothing like this.

Does anyone know as to how to build such an app using HTML5 Builder?

Basically HTML5 builder is using PhoneGap to build Mobile apps.

TIA

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by 'send SMS from Mobile' ... send from a user's phone #, or send an sms to a user?

Comment: cross-posted to [Google groups -> here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/nYoRRDLphxI)